# Java multiple JPanels not working properly and overlaping

Tags: java

I use 3 panels and set bounds at the same position. When certain button is pressed I set visibility false or trough depending on what button is pressed. First two panels work alright, but third one spans all over. All three have same settings and are added to a same frame.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4pUc.png)

EDIT:

```
    dugme1 = new JButton("Laka");
    dugme1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            panelLaka.setVisible(true);
            panelSrednja.setVisible(false);                            //dugme 1
            panelTeska.setVisible(false);
        }
    });
    panelLaka = new JPanel();                      //niz od 10 lakih pitanja
    panelSrednja = new JPanel();                   //niz od 10 srednjih pitanja
    panelTeska = new JPanel();

    nizLaka = new JButton[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        nizLaka[i] = new JButton(""+(i+1));

        panelLaka.add(nizLaka[i]);

    }

    panelLaka.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("LAKA KATEGORIJA"));
    panelLaka.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 5));
    panelLaka.setVisible(false);

    panelLaka.setBounds(10, 120, 465, 100);
    panelSrednja.setBounds(10, 120, 465, 100);
    panelTeska.setBounds(10, 120, 465, 100);

    frame.add(panelLaka);
    frame.add(panelSrednja);
    frame.add(panelTeska);

    frame.setVisible(true);
```

All of the code is too big but I added some important parts to give you the idea.

Comment: @cliff2310 I have added the code.

Comment: That is swing and you should avoid setBounds and null layouts. [FlowLayout or GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) might be your best options.

Comment: @Matthew Even if I am hiding some panels?

Comment: I see you are trying it by `setVisible()`. That is why it isn't working. [CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for your JFrame is what might be you are looking for.

Comment: @Matthew It looks like it could be the solution. I'll try it out and get back.
Still I'm not sure why it works for first two panels and for third not.

Comment: I highly suggest you take Matthew's advice and look into `CardLayout`. It was designed specifically to support switching between different panels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what's causing the problem but I added another empty panel. Card Layout can also be useful